# How to paginate s3 bucket query using ruby gem for rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a query that fetches all the items inside an S3 bucket, and it takes a very long time to load if there are a lot of items in that bucket.

```
bucket.objects(prefix: 'path/to/items').collect(&:key)
```

Based on [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/Resources/Collection.html), I see it's possible to limit the number of items in that fetch.

```
bucket.objects(prefix: 'path/to/items').limit(10).collect(&:key)
```

However, I don't see any offset parameter for this function. Any idea how I could do pagination with this so it doesn't take so long to load the first few results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS provides some examples to how to do that [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/PageableResponse.html). It sounds like you should be able to call `.each` on `bucket.objects(prefix: 'path/to/items')` to handle each page as it is returned.

Automatic paging:

```rb
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new

s3.list_objects(bucket: 'aws-sdk').each do |response|
  puts response.contents.map(&:key)
end
```

Manual paging:

```rb
s3 = Aws::S3::Client.new

# Get the first page of data
response = s3.list_objects(bucket: 'aws-sdk')

# Get additional pages
while response.next_page? do
  response = response.next_page
  # Use the response data here...
  puts response.contents.map(&:key)
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mike! This worked, I defined the number of items per page using `max_keys`, and define the offset using `marker`, which contains the key of the last item on the previous page.